# Google Maps API Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Hope you guys can answer this question!  I'm thinking it should be relatively easy but I just can't seem to get to grips with it.

How do you go about loading the Google Maps API Javascript within a Wordpress post/page?

The Wordpress Codex would seem to suggest that having referred to your javascript file in the header of your theme you then need to call the functions within the post.

I've referred to the Google Javascript files in the header as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuU_0_uLMnFM-2oWod_fzC0atPZj7dHlU&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and then to my javascript file with all the API code in the header too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://runforlifeuk.com/rhedeg/wp-content/javascript/trefilmap.js"></script>
```

I've then used the following code in the post:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://runforlifeuk.com/rhedeg/wp-content/javascript/trefilmap.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<div id="map-canvas">
</div>
```

But this just creates an empty box.  I've tried calling the predefined Google JS functions within the post but this doesn't appear to have worked either.

Is there anybody implementing Google Maps on Wordpress that has already done this?  I can paste all the code directly into the post but the Google Map comes out full of bugs.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!
Many thanks.

Comment: How you want to use the map? As background or just as a box in your page? Also you want to place long and lat for your place or something else?

Answer (score 14):

With WordPress you should never hard code js into the header or footer. Instead use `wp_enqueue_script` inside a function hooked into the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action in functions.php. For example:

```
function add_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuU_0_uLMnFM-2oWod_fzC0atPZj7dHlU&sensor=false');
  wp_enqueue_script('google-jsapi','https://www.google.com/jsapi');     
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts')
```

You would want to prefix the function name with a unique slug. You could add dependencies version numbers or move it to the footer with additional variables, see the codex for more info. In your case you probably want to wrap `wp_enqueue_script` in a conditional so it only loads on the posts or pages you need it for.

Comment: I finally got it with very similar code to that above: `function google_maps_api() {

    wp_register_script( 'googlemap', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuU_0_uLMnFM-2oWod_fzC0atPZj7dHlU&sensor=false',true);
wp_register_script( 'elevation_service', 'https://www.google.com/jsapi',true);

wp_enqueue_script('googlemap');
wp_enqueue_script('elevation_service');  
  
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'google_maps_api' );`

Comment: Glad it worked. Using 'true' as your third variable isn't necessary. Nor is registering the script before enqueueing it. Registering scripts separately is only really necessary when you want to make conditional script enqueues simpler or if you are registering a script that will be a dependency for another script. Its fine the way you're doing it, its just redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a look at your `http://runforlifeuk.com/rhedeg/wp-content/javascript/trefilmap.js` file

you shouldn't have `<script>` tags in that!

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBuU_0_uLMnFM-2oWod_fzC0atPZj7dHlU&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

I would suggest you to have a look at the javascript console for errors and learn using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to add javascript to your pages.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!! I've managed to register and enqueue the Google Map API javascript library.  I've also placed the .js file for my javascript in the header of my theme.  The good news is that the map loads... The bad news is that map is horribly broken.  For example, the stems of infoboxes don't open, the close cross doesn't appear, the streetview pegman doesn't show up on the map.  All these things I know work on a plain HTML page.  When I copy the Javascript directly into the wordpress post I again get the same problem.  Switching my theme to TwentyEleven doesn't solve it.  Any ideas!!!!